# matlab oop reset property

Tags: matlab, oop, properties

I try to remove an entry from matlab class properties vector, from inside class function. The correct element get removed but the old entries doesn't get overriden.

That's my class:

```
classdef unknownPoints    
    properties
        points;
    end

    methods
        function removePoint(obj, num)
            points = obj.points(obj.points ~= num)  [1]
        end
    end
end
```

which i am calling like that:

```
up = unknownPoints();
up.points = [up.points 3];
up.points = [up.points 2];
up.points = [up.points 7];
up.removePoint(3);
up.points   [2]
```

The result is:

```
points = 2     7        <-- from inside the method    [1]
ans    = 3     2     7  <-- and that how it looks like from outside [2]
```

What i expect to read from the outside would be like the first => [2, 7] result, but it seems the 'points' property doesn't get overriden.
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please use commends to add informations like `[1]` to your code. Instead use `%[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
classdef unknownPoints < handle   
    properties
        points;
    end

    methods
        function removePoint(obj, num)
            obj.points = obj.points(obj.points ~= num)
        end
    end
end
```

You created a local variable `points` instead of modifying the object variable.

Comment: I fixed my answer. The way you intend to use objects, you must use the supercalss `handle`. Details here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/handle.html

Comment: Thanks that works. I tried obj.points before but it didn't change anything wihtout the inheritance from `handle`. That seems to be the point also if i don't understand yet what it does

Comment: If you are used to other oo-programming languages, `handle` basically creates a similar behaviour with object reverences. Try: `x=ExampleClass,y=x,x.a=1,'. If Exampleclass implements handle, y is the same instance as well and both are modified. If not, y remains unchanged.